# O que os operadores de incrementação fazem em arrays?

Tags: php, array, operadores

Acidentalmente eu estava criando um script PHP e , sem querer, coloquei um operador de incrementação numa variável cujo tipo é `array`.

Para minha surpresa, nenhum erro foi mostrado pelo PHP.

Fiz alguns testes e constatei que realmente isso não gera erro para variáveis do tipo `array`.

Teste:

```
$dados['nome'] = 'wallace';

$empty = array();

$dados++;

$empty--;

print_r($dados);

print_r($empty);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [nome] => wallace
)
Array
(
)
```

Antes que alguém faça um comentário ou questione coisas como "E por que você esperava que isso retornasse um erro?", eu explico.

Que eu saiba operadores de incremento e decremento funcionam para valores do tipo `int` (com exceção da incrementação no PHP, que incrementa letras :p).

Então, em se tratando de soma de valores `int` com `array`, a expressão abaixo retornaria um `Fatal Error`:

```
$dados = array();

$dados + 1
```

Erro gerado:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

O operador de soma em `arrays` operam para que os valores do `array` da esquerda sejam inseridos no `array` da direita, caso não existam:

```
['nome' => 'wallace'] + ['idade' => 23, 'nome' => 'Wayne']
```

Resultado:

```
['nome' => 'wallace', 'idade' => 23]
```

Sendo assim, tenho umas perguntas:

- Por que o PHP não gera nenhum aviso ou erro quando uso operadores de incrementação ou decrementação em arrays?
- Isso poderia ser considerado um bug?
- Existe alguma utilidade em usar o operador de incrementação em `array` que eu não tenha notado?

Comment: Sim, PHP é um *bug* :D

Comment: @bigown eu vou ser sincero com você: Sei que o php tem muitos erros, mas gosto muito dele. Seu comentário mereceu um operador de decrementação

Comment: Até ocorre o erro, mas o PHP não consegue identificar o erro, se você tentar isso: `<?php ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(-1);
echo $empty[]; ?>` não mostra erro nenhum, mas se mostrar isso: dá erro: `<?php ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(-1);
echo $empty; ?>` é como um bug mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Os operadores incremento/decremento afetam apenas números e strings. Arrays, objetos e recursos não são afetados. Decrementar NULL não gera efeitos, mas incrementar resulta em 1.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 2):

Não acontece um erro ao utilizar o operador de in/decremento em um array ou objeto pois nada é afetado conforme a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) diz:

> Note: The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and strings. Arrays, objects and resources are not affected.

Comment: Aí o php tendo isso em vista deveria lançar um erro. Eita PHP, mesmo assim eu amo você

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, também acho que deveria retornar um `Unsupported operand types`